# In assembly code, changing stack pointer + jump -> segfault?

Tags: gcc, x86, inline-assembly, att

This is the first time uploading a question here.
I have to make a function that:

1. arguments are: a target function & a global array
2. set registers %ebp & %esp = array
3. set register %eip = target function
4. using **asm**, in-line assembly code in C

If I ignore the second condition, it is not difficult at all:

```
void jump(unsigned int function);
void goal();

void main(){
    jump((unsigned int)goal); // call jump(goal)
}

void jump(unsigned int function){
    __asm__ __volatile__(
            "movl %0, %%eax;"
            "jmp %%eax" // jump to 'entry'
            ::"m"());
}

void goal(){ // desired destination of %eip
    printf("goal\n"); // if jmp instruction was successful, put 'goal'
    for(;;) { sleep(1); }
}
```

And it indeed puts 'goal'.

However, whenever I try to change %esp & %ebp in the similar manner I failed:

(main changes are just declaration of 'array' and 2 lines in the middle of **asm**)

```
int array[100]; // target array
void jump(unsigned int function, unsigned int array);
void goal();

void main(){
    jump((unsigned int)goal, (unsigned int)array); // call jump(goal,array)
}

void jump(unsigned int function, unsigned int array){
    __asm__ __volatile__(
            "movl %0, %%eax;"
            "movl %1, %%ebx;"

            "movl %%ebx, %%esp;" // %esp = array
            "movl %%ebx, %%ebp;" // %ebp = array

            "jmp %%eax"
            ::"m"(function),"m"(array));
}

void goal(){
    printf("goal\n");
    for(;;) { sleep(1); }
}
```

This makes a segmentation fault.

In .s file entry of the 'goal' function contains a prologue as all functions do, i.e.

```
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
```

So my first guess was, pointing somewhere like global array by %ebp or %esp and then doing push, pop or mov makes segment fault.

To verify this I modified assembly part as the following:

```
         __asm__ __volatile__(
         "movl %0, %%eax;"
         "movl %1, %%ebx;"
         "movl %%ebp, %%ecx;" // %ecx : backup of %ebp

         "movl %%ebx, %%esp;"
         "movl %%ebx, %%ebp;" // %esp & %ebp = 'array'

         "pushl %%ebp;"
         "movl %%esp, %%ebp;" // instructions as in the entry of 'goal'

         "movl %%ecx, %%esp;"
         "movl %%ecx, %%ebp;" // restore %esp & %ebp before jmp

         "jmp %%eax"
         ::"m"(function),"m"(array));
```

So that %esp and %ebp point 'array' and follow the instructions in the 'goal' before the jmp.

Surprisingly no segmentation fault happened but puts 'goal' as desired.

In summary,

1. changing %esp & %ebp doesn't matter.
2. jmp also works.
3. but doing both makes a segmentation fault.

I googled and look around especially here for someone suffered this phenomenon and found the answer. Unfortunately found nothing.

Hope for help.

Comment: tl;dr you want to use inline-asm to call a function with a manually-allocated stack.  But you're using `jmp` not `call`, so what's supposed to happen when it returns?  Oh, it doesn't, infloop on `sleep(1)`.  So it's ok that you clobber `%ebx` without telling the compiler, I guess.  (don't have time to look at this question in detail now, but you should use `gdb` to find out which instruction setfaults, and edit that info into the question.  Along with register values and/or stack memory contents at the point where you get a segfault.)

Comment: I've never used `gdb`, but will learn and try. Thanks for your tip.

Comment: Writing asm without a debugger is like trying to build a robot blindfolded.  It's a great way to learn how instructions change the state of the machine.  (And for inline-asm, to single-step into compiler-generated code, too.)  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for some GDB / strace tips.

Comment: `gdb` told me that the segfault occured **after** the jump. So I erased printf and sleep, so that only for(;;){} remains after the jump. Then there is no segfault. By which means, anyway jump was successful, but any system call after that seems to be unstable.

Comment: More likely any use of the stack crashed.  An inf loop without any calls won't try to push anything onto the stack, so it won't crash if ESP is messed up (which I assume is what happened).  Check with the debugger that ESP is pointing near the top of the buffer you allocated.  (You can use control-C inside GDB to interrupt the process you're debugging, like a breakpoint not killing the program.)

Comment: As you told me I traced %esp using `bt`. But the stack pointer was pointing somewhere strange in '_dl_fixup' in 'dl_run_resolve'. So I googled it and found that it's called 'dynamic linking', which can be avoided by adding `-static` option to gcc compiler. Now my program finally puts 'goal'!!! Thank you so much... it is definitely worth to join here.